# How to pass data from one partial view to another partial View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am developing a application in MVC.

I have one view in which I have bind two partial Views.

What I am trying to do is, I want to pass the data from one partial view to another partial view.

In below example, Product list partial view gives total of prices of product list and that total I want to pass to Taxation partial view to calculate tax on total value.

Its should be done at run time.

How to do this ?

[image]

My Parent View

```
    @model CRMEntities.Quotation
    @{
    }

     <span class="ProductForm row-fluid">
     @Html.Action("QuotationRelatedProductList", "Quotation", new { Id = @Model.Id })
     </span>
```

> ```
> Product Partial View
> ```

```
    @model IEnumerable<CRMEntities.QuotationProduct>

    <div id="divOpportunityProduct">
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            i = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
 <input class="clsPrice" name='ProductPrice' type='text' id='txtPrice-@i' value="@EachProdPrice" style='font-size:12px;width:50px;margin-left:12px;' @*readonly="true"*@/>

<input name="Total" class="clsTotal" type='text' id='lblTotal-@i' style ='font-size:12px;width:50px;margin-left:14px;' @*readonly="true"*@/>
            }
        }        

<div class="pull-left row-fluid" style="margin-top: 5px;">@Html.TextBox("txtGrandTotal", null, new {style="width:110px;"})</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

  function GetGrandTotal() {
        var AddTotal = 0;
        var EachTotal;
        $('input.clsTotal').each(function (index) {

            var d = "lblTotal-" + index;

            EachTotal = $('#' + d).val();

            var y = new Number(EachTotal);

            AddTotal = (AddTotal + y);

        });

        $("#txtGrandTotal").val(AddTotal);

    }

</script>
```

Now, the Above grand Total Value , i want to pass to another view at runtime....

Comment: Your time would have been better spent writing code describing what you have already tried instead of making up a graphic.

Comment: ok, but Code is too bulky to put here...

Comment: Please check the code...

Answer (score 1):

A. Calculate your totals in your business logic, on server (in controller). Pass that along with your view model. Give that to both of your partial views.

B. Partials are rendered on server. Javascript only works with complete page. There are no partials for JS. So if you do some JS in one view, it is also available to another - save results into global variable and access that from other part of the script. But this is a poor technique.

Just look at the resulting page in your browser and see how JS works there.